# Pass data frame and reference it for assignment inside function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, variable-assignment

I'm getting tripped up on assigning after passing a data frame through a function.
The real function is much larger but below is an example.
The goal: If the quarter column name is in the active_quarters vector, do nothing. If it isn't, assign blanks to all the values in that column of the data frame.

I understand it's trying to reference "some_data_frame" explicitly, but I'm blanking, pun intended, on how to properly assign the blanks given the iteration of the loop.

code:

```
library(dplyr)
active_quarters <- c("Q1", "Q2")

data_frame_dummy <- data.frame("Q1" = c(1:4),
                               "Q2" = c(5:8),
                               "Q3" = c(9:12),
                               "Q4" = c(13:16))

create_blanks<- function(quarters_list,some_data_frame){

  for(qcols in c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")){
    if(qcols %in% quarters_list){
      next
    }else{
      some_data_frame[,qcols] <<- ""
      
    }
  } # End of quarter if/else
} # End of function

create_blanks(active_quarters, data_frame_dummy)
```

result:

```
> create_blanks(active_quarters, data_frame_dummy)
Error in some_data_frame[, qcols] <<- "" : 
  object 'some_data_frame' not found
```

desired result:

```
> data_frame_dummy
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  1  5      
2  2  6      
3  3  7      
4  4  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use `<<-` unless absolutely necessary.  Functions shouldn't change existing objects.  So just have the function return `some_data_frame` and then assign it explicitly as needed.

```
create_blanks<- function(quarters_list,some_data_frame){
  
  for(qcols in c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")){
    if(qcols %in% quarters_list){
      next
    }else{
      some_data_frame[,qcols] <- ""
      
    }
  } # End of quarter if/else
  some_data_frame
} # End of function
data_frame_dummy <- create_blanks(active_quarters, data_frame_dummy)
data_frame_dummy
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  1  5      
2  2  6      
3  3  7      
4  4  8
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're saying. I was using the double assignment to find the error. But I think this will work. I didn't think about reassigning it to the name of the data frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? You can negate the selection if you want to assign 0 to the columns not in the .col parameters

```r
library(tidyverse)

active_quarters <- c("Q1", "Q2")

data_frame_dummy <- data.frame("Q1" = c(1:4),
                               "Q2" = c(5:8),
                               "Q3" = c(9:12),
                               "Q4" = c(13:16))


data_frame_dummy |> 
  mutate(across(!active_quarters,.fns = ~ 0))
#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> i Use `all_of(active_quarters)` instead of `active_quarters` to silence this message.
#> i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
#> This message is displayed once per session.
#>   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
#> 1  1  5  0  0
#> 2  2  6  0  0
#> 3  3  7  0  0
#> 4  4  8  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You can also polish the selection by using all_of as dplyr is suggesting

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but this actually helps me with some other issues, so thanks!